# Usar un Formulario externo

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo mi aplicación en **C#**, necesito poder rellenar tres campos en otra aplicación , estoy usando este código para levantar la otra aplicación y enviar **sendkeys**

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string className, string windowTitle);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, ShowWindowEnum flags);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hwnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool GetWindowPlacement(IntPtr hWnd, ref Windowplacement lpwndpl);

        private enum ShowWindowEnum
        {
            Hide = 0,
            ShowNormal = 1, ShowMinimized = 2, ShowMaximized = 3,
            Maximize = 3, ShowNormalNoActivate = 4, Show = 5,
            Minimize = 6, ShowMinNoActivate = 7, ShowNoActivate = 8,
            Restore = 9, ShowDefault = 10, ForceMinimized = 11
        };

        private struct Windowplacement
        {
            public int length;
            public int flags;
            public int showCmd;
            public System.Drawing.Point ptMinPosition;
            public System.Drawing.Point ptMaxPosition;
            public System.Drawing.Rectangle rcNormalPosition;
        }

        public void TraerVentanaAlFrente(string proceso)
        {
            IntPtr wdwIntPtr = FindWindow(null, proceso);

            //Obtener el hWnd del proceso
            Windowplacement placement = new Windowplacement();
            GetWindowPlacement(wdwIntPtr, ref placement);

            // Verificar si la ventana esta minimizada
            if (placement.showCmd == 2)
            {
                //Si la ventana esta minimizada restaurarla
                ShowWindow(wdwIntPtr, ShowWindowEnum.Restore);
            }

            //Hacer foco en la ventana
            SetForegroundWindow(wdwIntPtr);
        }
```

Esta parte funciona bien, con el código pueda levantar y hacer **focus** en la otra aplicación , el problema es que la otra aplicación tiene dos ventanas distintas, y siempre me hace **focus** en la *ventana 1* y necesito que me haga focus en la *ventana 2*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Así me quedo

Clase

```
class TraerVentana
{
    static private string nombreVentana;

    public static string NombreVentana
    {
        get { return TraerVentana.nombreVentana; }
        set { TraerVentana.nombreVentana = value; }
    }

    public delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder strText, int maxCount);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc enumProc, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hwnd);

    //Antes de utilizar asignar un valor a nombreVentana
    public static bool EnumTheWindows(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        int size = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
        if (size++ > 0 && IsWindowVisible(hWnd))
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(size);
            GetWindowText(hWnd, sb, size);
            if (sb.ToString() == nombreVentana)
            {
                SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Implementacion

```
TraerVentana.NombreVentana = "Nombre de ventana";
TraerVentana.EnumWindows(new TraerVentana.EnumWindowsProc(TraerVentana.EnumTheWindows), IntPtr.Zero);
```

Answer (score 1):

Si esa segunda ventana es "hija" de la primera, puedes utilizar [FindWindowEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/ms633500(v=vs.85).aspx) para buscar usando el primer puntero que te devuelve `FindWindow`.

Otro método que te puede servir es [EnumWindows](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/EnumWindows.html), que devuelve todas las ventanas.

Comment: Deberia usar esto no?
static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHWnd, IntPtr childAfterHWnd, string className, string windowTitle); Que parametros debo pasarle?

Comment: @AlejandroRicotti mira aqui lo explica todo (en ingles) [pInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.findwindowex). Si no lo consigues me comentas,es que ahora no estoy delante del ordenador

Comment: Ese link que pusiste lo vi, pero no entendi mucho, creo que no es lo que necesito, lo que necesito es que me traiga al frente la ventana hijo de otro form externo a la aplicacion. Creo que esto puede llegar a servir http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710003/findwindowex-on-child-dialog-window pero no estoy seguro como implementarlo

Comment: También vi que de parámetro aparece que recibe un WindowsTitle y en realidad lo que va es el ejecutable de la aplicacion, no el nombre de titulo que se muestra

Answer (score 0):

Conseguí este código que a diferencia de usar FindWindow y FindWindowEx los cuales trabajan por proceso utiliza el nombre que aparece en la barra de tareas

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

namespace EnumWindows
{
    class Program
    {
        protected delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);

`[DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hwnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    protected static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder strText, int maxCount);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    protected static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    protected static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc enumProc, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    protected static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);

    protected static bool EnumTheWindows(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        int size = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
        if (size++ > 0 && IsWindowVisible(hWnd))
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(size);
            GetWindowText(hWnd, sb, size);
            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
            if (sb.ToString() == "NOMBRE DE CARPETA O APLICACION")
            {
                SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        EnumWindows(new EnumWindowsProc(EnumTheWindows), IntPtr.Zero);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}`

Esto lo que hace es listar todos los elementos de la barra de herramientas, y hacer focus en el que ingresemos, me falta adaptarlo en una clase para poder implementarlo en mi aplicacion de forms